# Where do you get a travel adaptor in Ireland?

Tags: ireland, power

You arrive in Ireland and realise, oh no, you forgot to pack your travel adaptor. Unfortunately you are going to need one while you're here. That is the situation I'm in.
Where can I get a new one that fits my plugs? Are there any electronic stores that might carry some (so far, I haven't seen any)? Or perhaps, my best bet is to order online?

Comment: Where are you at? What type of plugs do you have?

Comment: Euro plugs can be plugged in without a travel adaptor.

Comment: @JonathanReez - Looks like there are some significant caveats from the info in the description here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUu1anFXjUc

Comment: I don't reccomend plugging europlugs into british sockets but if you must do it then you should at least use an extension lead so that a fuse is present and so that if the plug does get stuck you aren't left with your appliance permanently attatched to the wall.

Comment: If you're staying in a hotel, you can start by asking the front desk. It's common for them to have a variety around, either as a service for their guests, or simply because people leave them behind and they wind up with a big box of unclaimed adapters in the lost and found.

Answer (score 13):

Tourist-junk shops will normally carry them. So, anywhere you see selling Shamrock-themed tat and big green Leprechaun hats are worth a shot.

Homeware and electricals stores are also an option - as can be DIY stores.

Particular places I found that advertise them online and might have a store near you:

- [Boots (A pharmacy chain)](http://www.boots.ie/en/Sun-Holiday/Travel/Plugs-and-adaptors/)
- [Argos (hard to describe - like a warehouse you can go to and people bring stuff to you from out back)](http://www.argos.ie/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?storeId=10152&catalogId=14551&langId=111&searchTerms=travel%20adapter&authToken=)
- [Currys (an electricals chain that may also go by the name PC World)](http://www.currys.ie/category/travel-accessories/397.9)
- [DID Electricals (another electricals chain)](http://www.did.ie/uk-ireland-travel-adapter-prd)

All these I found by [searching "travel adapter" on google.ie](https://www.google.ie/#q=travel+adapter). (Although most of the linked chains I know from the UK).

### Important Safety Notice:

Be careful if your device needs earthing, that the adapter you use properly passes the earth through. Many of the adapters shown either don't, or only do for some types of plug (and Europe has many slightly different types)

Comment: You can also add [Eurogiant](http://www.eurogeneral.ie/) discount stores and the likes. There are plenty of these in Dublin downtown, and they usually have the adaptors. Also, if one happens to be outside of downtown, most of mentioned options might be quite far, but big Tesco stores may have these

Comment: I bought a rather fancy one, so-called "universal," in one of the airport shops in Manchester.

Comment: I lost mine in Galway, and bought another in Dunnes.  And I'm now in the Dublin airport where3 several shops have them.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have experiance with ireland but I do live in the UK and I expect the situation is similar.

In the UK one commonly sees generic "visitor" adaptors. These are widely available in most supermarkets and many other shops. They will look something like this:

[image]

http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/9827590.htm

Typically they will accept american plugs, australian plugs and most European plugs. They may also accept 5A BS546 plugs (often listed as indian plugs). They will almost certainly NOT accept 15A BS546 plugs (often listed as south african plugs).

German/French plugs will typically be accepted but will not be earthed.

Unfortunately while the generic adaptors are as common as muck (at least in the UK but from the other answer it seems similar in ireland) if you need something that they don't cover you are likely to struggle. You might find earthed adaptors for German Shuko plugs with some searching. Anything else will probablly have to be ordered online.

Rewirable plugs should also be fairly widely available so if you are really stuck then changing the plug may be an option.

For computer gear getting a new power cord may also be an option.